# How to refresh ListView using SwipeRefreshLayout after checked a RSS title information using AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

This is my situation. I have a fragment with ListView. That contain the news titles downloaded by RSS.
When the user refresh fragment using SwipeRefreshLayout (sliding the finger from up and down as twitter app) I check if exist new RSS items and after download the new information I want to refresh the listView.

I download the new information ok using AsyncTask and add into my avisosList (arraylist) But my problem is in the listView.

How to refresh ListView with the new information?

This is my onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rss_avisos_fragment, container, false);       
    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.rss_avisos_lv);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    // Nuevo Elemento: Swipe Refresh Layout
    swipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rss_avisos_swipeRefreshLayout);
    swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeRefresh.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark,
    android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
    android.R.color.holo_green_dark,
    android.R.color.holo_red_light);

    return view;
}
```

onRefresh()

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DowloadTest dow = new DowloadTest();
    dow.execute();      
}
```

DowloadesTest class extends AsynctTask.

```
    public class DowloadTest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        };

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            buscaNuevasNoticasRss();
            return null;
        }


        private void buscaNuevasNoticasRss() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//Here I check RSS and if is necessary I add new items into avisosList and execute a Toast.

...
            if(avisosList.size()>=1){
                String lang = (String)  mirarIdioma();
                insertarNuevosAvisos(avisosList, lang);
                try {
                    new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Looper.prepare();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Existen nuevos avisos.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                     
                            Looper.loop();
                        }
                    }.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }else{
                try {
                    new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Looper.prepare();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "NO HAY NOTICIAS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Looper.loop();
                        }
                    }.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }

        }
```

OnPostExecute.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Update your UI here
         swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
        AvisosEnListaAdapter adapter = new              AvisosEnListaAdapter(getActivity(), avisosList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        return;
    }
```

I don't receive any error but the ListView doesn't refresh.

Comment: You need to pass the result from `doInBackground` so you can use the result in `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found good solution for me.

Now thi is onPostExecute code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Update avisosList (arrayList) from DB
    DataBaseHelper myDB = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    myDB.openDataBase();
    avisosList = myDB.getAllAvisos(lang);
    tratarFechaParaPublicar(avisosList, lang);

    adapter.refresh(avisosList);
    swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);


    return;
}
```

And I need add `refresh(arrayList)` method into my adapter.

```
 public void refresh(ArrayList<Aviso> itemsw) {
        this.items = itemsw;     
        Log.d("Testing2", "AvisosEnListaAdapter. refresh(). Actualizando adaptador");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```